# If $X$ is binomial (n,p) what is the distribution of $n - X$?

Tags: probability

Question in title. I know the anwer, but I don't know how to derive it

Comment: Could you tell us your answer?

Comment: Why is the question put on hold? So I guess it's illegal to ask questions on this site if one doesn't already have some sort of clue on how to solve it? Yeah, that makes perfect sense. Very useful site, this.

Answer (score 2):

The binomial distribution is the distribution of the number $X$ of successes in $n$ independent Bernoulli trials with success probability $p$. Since $n-X$ is the number of failures, its distribution is the binomial distribution with the same number of trials and "success" probability given by the failure probability $1-p$, i.e. $\operatorname{Binomial}(n,1-p)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y = n - X$, then 
$$ P\{Y = k\} = P\{n-X = k\} = P\{X=n-k\}$$,
and now that you know $X \sim b(n,p)$, you can do the rest of derivation.

Hope it helps :)